# Exclude beginning string from regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a piece of regex that looks like this:

```
/^.*website.localdev$/
```

This matches `website.localdev` as well as any subdomain like `www.website.localdev` fine.

I need to adapt it to exclude a string ("foo") at the beginning of the regex, so that `"website.localdev"` and `"www.website.localdev"` still matches but `"foo.website.localdev"` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?!foo\.).*?website.localdev$/
```

You can see it in action on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/7AiK8ilyEq)

Comment: but this will not only exclude `foo.website.localdev` but also `fool.website.localdev`

Comment: `^(?!foo\.).*?website.localdev$`: two improvements here. Cares about `foo.` and works in multiline mode (because of non-greedy search.)